# how to parse dynamic complex json to dart object or model

Tags: json, flutter, dart

```
{
"transactionId": "11f8ecc05273e35a4eb2dc1a",
"type": "REQUEST_FOR_HH_INTERVIEW",
"answers": {
  "selectProvinceDistrictCommuneVillage": {
    "value": "01020706"
  },
  "positionOfOfficial": {
    "value": "Province Officer"
  },
  "enterKhmerName": {
    "value": "សុខ"
  },
  "selectSex": {
    "value": "MALE"
  },
  "dob": {
    "value": "1994-06-15T03:27:47.409Z"
  },
  "areYouMarried": {
    "value": "YES"
  },
  "scanSpousesID": {
    "value": "435465"
  },
  "enterSpousesKhmerName": {
    "value": "នារី"
  },
  "selectSexSpouse": {
    "value": "FEMALE"
  },
  "dobSpouse": {
    "value": "1996-08-15T03:27:47.409"
  },
  "numberOfMales": {
    "value": "4"
  },
  "numberOfFemales": {
    "value": "5"
  },
  "selectReasonForRequesting": {
    "value": [
      "NATURAL_DISASTER"
    ]
  }
}
}
```

So this is the JSON I need to parse into the dart model. The problem I am having with this structure is that map inside answers are all dynamic. Also, the number of the maps inside answers is not always the same. For example, the next JSON response can be.

```
{
 "transactionId": "11f8ecc05273e35a4eb2dc1a",
 "type": "REQUEST_FOR_HH_INTERVIEW",
 "answers": {
   "selectCode": {
   "value": "01020706"
  },
  "selectRoomValue": {
  "value": "1996-08-15T03:27:47.409"
 },
 "numberOfFamilyMembers": {
  "value": "4"
  },
 "selectFoods": {
   "value": [
     "Piza",
     "Burger"
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

which is different from the first response. I need to make a dart model that parses both responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively easy to do by using a "sub-model" of `Answers` which would be stored within the assumed `InterviewRequest` model.

For example:

```dart
class InterviewRequest {
  final Answers answers;
  final String transactionId;

  factory InterviewRequest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return InterviewRequest(
      answers: Answers.fromJson(json['answers']),
      transactionId: json['transactionId'] as String,
    );
  }
}

class Answers {
  final List<Answer> answers;

  factory Answers.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List answers = [];
    for (String question in json.keys)
      answers.add(Answer(question, json[key]));
    return Answers(answers);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you kindly also mention how the sub-model will look.

Comment: @AabhashRai The sub-model is just another class, and would look very similar to the `InterviewRequest` class.

Comment: I wasn't able to make a submodel for the answer. I don't think there is a way to make a submodel as an interview for an answer because the fields inside the answer are all dynamic. So I just kept the answer as type dynamic. ie final dynamic answer;

Comment: No offense, but you shouldn't be asking people on the internet to "do your homework". That said, there is no such thing as a "sub-model" in Dart. Or even a "model" for that matter. It's just a term. At the end of the day, these are just classes, and we as developers have the control over their function. I showed you how to do it, and provided you with the information you need to do the rest. Please mark the answer as accepted, and good luck with your interview.

Comment: No offense taken :). 
I would have marked your answer accepted if it did anything for me.
anyway, thank you for taking some time to help me.

Comment: My answer shows "how to parse dynamic json" and leaves one step for the developer to complete. You learn by doing, not copying. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know how to parse a JSON. I just wanted to know if there is a way to parse a map with dynamic fields by creating a model. Your answer just says to create another model and my question was how.
Your answer is, how do I cook an egg? It's simple just cook it in a pan.

Comment: Also as I said before I did fix the issue but not by creating a separate object or model for the answer.

Comment: I've added the `Answers` class for you. As you can see, it's exactly the same as the `InterviewRequest` class. I left the `Answer` class for you to decide how to handle it. You could also get rid of it and use a simple map, but it's always better to use your own data models than generic ones.